I'm trying to load a flat file into Mariadb. My code works on a different database, but on this data / db, I get a 1064 error
This code (truncated) works:
    SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';
    SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
    'E:\\MM012224.txt'
    INTO TABLE `denton24`.`mm012224`
    (@row)
    SET Account_Number = TRIM(SUBSTR(@ROW,1,30)),
    SPTB_Code = TRIM(SUBSTR(@ROW,31,3)),

BUT THEN THIS SIMILAR CODE DOES not WORK [error 1064 - you have an error in your SQL syntax]:
    SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';
    SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
    'E:\\tax_roll.txt'
    INTO TABLE `dallas24`.`tax_roll`
    (@row)
    SET ACCOUNT = TRIM(SUBSTR(@ROW,1,34)),
    SET YEAR = TRIM(SUBSTR(@ROW,35,4)),
    SET JURISDICTION = TRIM(SUBSTR(@ROW,39,4)),

I have tried to look at system variables to see if there's a system variable that needs changed, but I'm a neophyte in that area.  I did confirm my account does have FILE permission.
The (@row) use inputs the flat file by parsing the location of the various fields using TRIM(SUBSTR(@ROW,1,34))
The syntax appears identical, but one works and the other does not.

The non-working code has extra SET keywords; there should be only one.
When you get a syntax error, the part where it shows where in the request the error was noticed is important; please try to provide complete error messages.

It has always worked with SET before each new variable.  But I took your suggestion and removed all but one SET keyword, and VOILA -- the query ran.  7 minutes later and I'm rewarded with 5M new rows in my table...  Mega Thanks.
